# Google apps gem for Omniauth 1.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth, google-apps

I wish to use `somedomainname` with Omnniauth along with Devise. Thus i will have to use `google-apps gem`.

In the [Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview), it is mentioned that the gem has not been updated for OmniAuth 1.0

Is there any possible gem that i can use for this purpose ?

Also, i have also noticed [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-google-apps) that it is compatible but it isn't. 
I keep getting the below error when i say `rake routes on the terminal`

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- omniauth-google_apps
```

Comment: Tried omniauth-google-apps gem and not google-apps. Works like a charm.